# How to add text to a lattice wireframe in R

Tags: r, text, lattice, wireframe

Good Day All,

I want to add text floating in my wireframe plot and I am rather confused.  I can certainly add the text as a title (e.g. main="Hello World") but I would rather not have my particular text in the title

Here is a sample wireframe:

```
  library(lattice)
  #set up some simplified data
  x <- seq(-.8, .8, .1)
  y <- seq(-.8, .8, .1)
  myGrid <- data.frame(expand.grid(x,y))
  colnames(myGrid) <- c("x","y")
  myGrid$z <- myGrid$x + myGrid$y

  wireframe(
     myGrid$z ~ myGrid$x * myGrid$y, 
     xlab="X", ylab="Y", zlab="Z",
     scales = list(z.ticks=5, arrows=FALSE, col="black", font=3, tck=1)
  )
```

If I wanted to add "Hello World" in this plot floating somewhere how would I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the panel function and add text with `grid.text`.

```
wireframe(
    myGrid$z ~ myGrid$x * myGrid$y, 
    xlab="X", ylab="Y", zlab="Z",
    scales = list(z.ticks=5, arrows=FALSE, col="black", font=3, tck=1),
    panel = function(...)
    {
      panel.wireframe(...)
      grid.text("some text", 0, 0, default.units = "native")
    }
)
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the "some text" will plot inside the graph itself.  Is there a way to have it floating outside the graph ?

Comment: You can turn off text being clipped to the panel via `trellis.par.get("clip")`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could add the text after you plotted your wireframe with

```
grid::grid.text("some text", x=unit(0.7, "npc"), y=unit(0.8, "npc"))
```

The `unit` function allows you to specify the location of the text. If you use `"npc"` as your unit, the total width and height of your graph is 1. So the example above would display your text in the top right corner while `x=y=unit(0.5, "npc")` would plot it in the center.